# extracting string using regular expression

Tags: python, regex, string, parsing

I have the following input string

```
input= """href="http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167923609002097" onmousedown="return scife_clk(this.href,'','res','2')">Using <b>text mining </b>and sentiment analysis for online forums hotspot detection and forecast</a></h3><div class="gs_a">N Li, <a href="/citations?
    href="http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3309177/" onmousedown="return scife_clk(this.href,'ggp','res','1')">How to link ontologies and protein–protein interactions to literature: <b>text</b>-<b>mining </b>approaches and the BioCreative experience</a></h3><div class="gs_a"><a href="/citations?
    href="http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3309177/" onmousedown="return scife_clk(this.href,'gga','gga','1')"><span class="gs_ggsL"><span class=gs_ctg2>[HTML]</span> from nih.gov</span><span class="gs_ggsS">nih.gov <span """
```

I want to extract the following output from this:

```
>> Using <b>text mining </b>and sentiment analysis for online forums hotspot detection and forecast
>> How to link ontologies and protein–protein interactions to literature: <b>text</b>-<b>mining </b>approaches and the BioCreative experience
```

I am trying to use re package in python but I am not clear what regular expression to use, since there are several patterns like :

```
(this.href,'','res','2')"> or (this.href,'ggp','res','2')"> or (this.href,'gga','gga','2')">
```

I am using this regular expression:

```
=re.search(r"(this.href,'ggp.?','res','.?/D')"
```

But it is not working for me. Can anyone tell what re to use?

Comment: Why not use a HTML parser instead? regular expressions are not the right tool here.

Comment: which HTML parser to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works with your example:

```
input= """\
href="http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167923609002097" onmousedown="return scife_clk(this.href,'','res','2')">Using <b>text mining </b>and sentiment analysis for online forums hotspot detection and forecast</a></h3><div class="gs_a">N Li, <a href="/citations?
href="http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3309177/" onmousedown="return scife_clk(this.href,'ggp','res','1')">How to link ontologies and protein–protein interactions to literature: <b>text</b>-<b>mining </b>approaches and the BioCreative experience</a></h3><div class="gs_a"><a href="/citations?
href="http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3309177/" onmousedown="return scife_clk(this.href,'gga','gga','1')"><span class="gs_ggsL"><span class=gs_ctg2>[HTML]</span> from nih.gov</span><span class="gs_ggsS">nih.gov <span """

import re

for line in input.splitlines():
    m=re.search(r'onmousedown=.*?">(.*)</a>',line)
    if m:
        print(m.group(1))
```

Prints:

```
Using <b>text mining </b>and sentiment analysis for online forums hotspot detection and forecast
How to link ontologies and protein–protein interactions to literature: <b>text</b>-<b>mining </b>approaches and the BioCreative experience
```

Bear in mind that using a Regex with HTML is potentially a mine field (or mind field!) and it usually recommended to use a parser. But with snippets, you can make it work...

Comment: This won't work if there are 2 or more `<a>` tags on the same line.

Answer (score 1):

You'd be much better off using a decent HTML Parser. Use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) for example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(input)

for link in soup.find_all('a', onmousedown=True):
    print link.text
```

which finds all `<a>` elements with an `onmousedown` attribute.